# Where does OS-X store Mail.app data - and likewise for other email clients

Tags: mac-osx

I would like to make them store data in a encrypted location.

I am also interested in Thunderbird, postbox etc...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Mail.app

Mail.app stores messages as .emlx files in `~/Library/Mail/TYPE-ACCOUNT/` eg. `~/Library/Mail/POP-user@example.com/`

#### [Thunderbird](http://www.mozillamessaging.com/thunderbird/)

Thunderbird stores it's data in `~/Library/Thunderbird/Profiles/[string].default/`. There are two folders, one called `Mail` that will hold the Local Folders and if you have an IMAP account a folder called `ImapMail` that will hold the IMAP messages if downloaded. The [string] is a random alphanumeric string.

#### [Postbox](http://www.postbox-inc.com/)

Postbox which is based off of Thunderbird stores it in much the same manner but at `~/Library/Application Support/Postbox/[string].default/`.

#### [GyazMail](http://www.gyazsquare.com/gyazmail/)

GyazMail stores it's data in `~/Library/Application Support/GyazMail (data)/`

#### [Mailsmith](http://www.barebones.com/products/mailsmith/)

MailSmith stores it's data in `~/Documents/Mailsmith User Data/`

---

To store you email in an encrypted location you can make an alias (`ln -s ORIGINAL DESTINATION` - eg. `ln -s ~/Library/Mail /Volumes/EncrypedImage/`) onto an encrypted disk image made using Disk Utility if you'd like. Just ensure that the disk image is available or you'll find the data is being stored in a folder at `/Volumes/EncryptedImage` instead of actually on the image.

Alternatively you could use FileVault that will encrypt your entire home folder. However if the messages are sitting on a server somewhere (eg. not removed by a POP account or using an IMAP account) then the messages are still available unencrypted on the mail server.

Answer (score 1):

It's in `~/Library/Mail`.

Comment: Wow awesome answer. Yes I am thinking FileVault in future, but space is a bit tight so I can't turn it on right now (as it needs space to do its work). Am also concerned over performance quirks with FileVault...